# How to read two variables under one read command and echo them separately?

Tags: linux, read

For example:

I want user to input A=a

and I have the command which I guess is totally wrong.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
read -p "Enter something:" frsstring=secstring
echo $frsstring
echo $secstring
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: get rid of the `=` between the two variable names.   If you want the user to enter two values separated by and `=` symbol, set `IFS='='` before the read.  e.g. `IFS== read -p "Enter something:" frsstring secstring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how could it be done with one command, but you could read the entire line, and then split it in the desired variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter something:" line
frsstring=`echo "$line" | cut -f1 -d'='`
secstring=`echo "$line" | cut -f2 -d'='`


echo $frsstring
echo $secstring
```

I hope it could help

Comment: Thank  you very much. It solved my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` you can use an array variable and change the IFS (internal field separator) special variable to `=` which normally contains space character, tab and newline to split words.

```
IFS='=' read -a arr -p "Enter something: "
echo "${arr[0]}"
echo "${arr[1]}"
```

Or you can use shell [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) to remove the longest suffix and prefix pattern from the string:

```
read -p "Enter something: " str
echo "${str%%=*}" # remove longest suffix pattern `=*`
echo "${str##*=}" # remove longest prefix pattern `*=`
```

Comment: Thank you Freddy for solving my problem.